# MySQL SELECT statement that counts the number of tracks sold

Tags: mysql

Here is the initial question:

Write a SELECT statement that counts the number of tracks sold (as found in the InvoiceLine table) and displays the TrackId and count for each track along with an overall total.

There are two tables in question (Track) and (Invoiceline). These two tables share a primary key of TrackId.

The table Track has 9 columns > TrackId, Name, AlbumId, MediaTypeId, GenreId, Composer, Milliseconds, Bytes, UnitPrice

The table InvoiceLine has 5 columns > InvoicelineId, InvoiceId, TrackId, UnitPirce, Quantity

The query i have is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(TrackId), TrackId FROM InvoiceLine;
```

But i believe this query isn't right for this question. 
any input would be welcomed!

Comment: Remember to `GROUP BY TrackId`

Comment: *"But i believe this query isn't right for this question."* Indeed your query should be invalid and should give a error  by SQL standards but MySQL allowes those statements. Unless TrackId is a unique columns then [Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) could be used.. like @Daniel is mentioning it looks like you are needing `GROUP BY TrackId` here

Comment: ok thanks guys!  will do more research into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  trackId, 
  COUNT(trackId) as total
FROM InvoiceLine
GROUP BY trackId;
```

This will show each track as one column, and the total frequency (number of times it is listed in the table) as another column:

```
| trackId | total|
| ---------------|
| track_1 |  5   |
| track_2 |  8   |
```